# Trigger não funciona

Tags: mysql, trigger

Não tenho muita prática em MySQL e preciso criar uma trigger para atualizar uma coluna de uma tabela quando  um novo registro é inserido, porém quando faça a inserção de uma nova linha, nada acontece. Já mudei tudo que podia e não consegui fazer a trigger funcionar. Onde está meu erro?

```
delimiter $$
create trigger Database.Atualiza_Compra

before insert on Database.CompraPagamento for each row

Begin

if new.metodo = 'metodo_compra'

then

 set new.tipo = concat(substring(new.numero_adicional, 31, 1),'-', new.tipo);
-- set new.tipo = '3-Tipo';

end if;
END$$
```

Obs: Quando eu faço uma compra outra tabelas também recebem registros semelhantes porém eu só preciso que essa tabela específica fique com a coluna nesse formato para minha API funcionar. Não sei se isso tem a ver.

Também tentei fazer como está comentado na trigger. Se o método for aquele, "setar" um valor direto e também não funcionou.

Pode ter algum problema em relação a aspas duplas, simples ou crase?

Quando eu faço o insert e a trigger não funciona, eu executo então um comando Update para atualizar a nova linha passando os mesmo parâmetros e funciona.

```
update Database.Atualiza_Compra 
set tipo = concat(substring(numero_adicional, 31, 1),'-', tipo)
where metodo = 'metodo_compra' and id = 1
```

Comment: Podes postar o esquema de tua tabela?

Comment: Se puder também poste o `INSERT` que esta tentando fazer. Olhando assim por cima, imagino que o problema possa estar no `IF`.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes, o insert é pelo sistema e como falei atinge outras tabelas. Se eu faço um Update nessa mesma tabela passando exatamente a concatenação ali exposta, funciona. Só não funciona na trigger. Creio que seja algo no if mesmo mas o que? Sintaxe?

Comment: Imagino que seja o conteúdo do campo `metodo`, o valor dele realmente é `metodo_compra`?

Comment: @RobertoFagundes sim, é isso mesmo. Eu passo esse mesmo conteúdo no **where** para fazer um script de update e ele entende normalmente.

Comment: Coloca na sua pergunta a `query` que esta sendo executada, pelo que você esta me falando, você esta executando um `UPDATE` e esperando uma `TRIGGER` `BEFORE INSERT` ser executada. Se for isso mesmo, não vai ser executada...

Comment: @VictorP coloca o `INSERT` que esta sendo feito, para essa `TRIGGER` funcionar é necessário passar o campo `metodo` com o valor `metodo_compra` no `INSERT`.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes o insert não é comando, é pela aplicação. O cliente faz uma compra. Quando ele escolhe determinado tipo de compra o campo método eu preciso que seja uma concatenação do tipo mais a informação adicional. Quando eu faço uma compra teste, olho no banco e a trigger não funcionou eu então executo aquele script de update pra deixar o campo do jeito que eu preciso. O insert não é um script manual e pela aplicação afeta outras tabelas. Mas eu só preciso que essa tabela e esse campo específico sejam alterados.

Comment: Sua aplicação de alguma forma monta uma `query` que é o comando `INSERT`, se você não tiver acesso para fazer a aplicação também colocar o campo `metodo` = `metodo_compra` neste comando `INSERT`, essa `TRIGGER` nunca vai funcionar.

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso ao código da aplicação, só a base de dados. Mas se sempre que eu faço uma compra de um tipo e sempre na coluna está 'metodo_compra' não significa que a aplicação está colocando o 'metodo_compra' ? E teria outro caminho?